# Xorg multiple screen position

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia, x-server

I'm trying to setup my three monitor for more like one day and i can't find any solution

[my target setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6kf8.png)

When i try to setup this in my nvidia-settings  it doesnt work, the primary display become the HDMI-0.. even if the "set primary display" checkbox is only checked on the DVI-D-0 monitor

I tried many different things like absolute negative position without success:

```
DVI-D-0  @ 0,0 
DP-1     @ -1920,0
HDMI-0   @ -3840, 0
```

my xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 390.77  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-14)  Tue Jul 10 23:18:15 PDT 2018

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.77  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-14)  Tue Jul 10 23:19:22 PDT 2018

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ XL2411Z"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 160.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 144.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "Primary" "yes"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 6GB"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: 1920x1080_120 +0+0, DP-1: 1920x1080 +1920+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Thanks